# Is there any possible way to make @foo="" when if params[:query] was nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When if params[:query] was nil, it gets error to display @messages in view.
How can I set "" to @foo when if params[:query] was nil?

```
@foo = params[:query]
@messages = 'I got this value' + @foo + 'etcs'
```

I want something like this

> @messages = 'I got this value' + (try(@foo) || "") + 'etcs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forcibly convert the value to a string using `to_s`.  `nil.to_s` results in a blank string.

```
@foo = params[:query].to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@messages = 'I got this value' + (@foo || "") + 'etcs'
```

Or with string interpolation, which call `to_s`:

```
@messages = "I got this value #{@foo} etcs"
```

Comment: While `||` will work here, it can bite in certain cases (i.e. `false || ""`). The `"#{..}"` form implicitly calls `to_s`.